# Weird redirect on web api call

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api

I have a ASP.net web API 2 project. On my local machine all calls work without any issues, but on the real server the calls to the API redirect to your-way.eu. Does anyone have an idea where this behavior might come from?

Update:
The redirect only occurs in the browser, not with fiddler. The redirect is of type 301.

Here is the JavaScript call we execute:

```
var data = null;

var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.withCredentials = true;

xhr.addEventListener("readystatechange", function () {
   if (this.readyState === 4) {
      console.log(this.responseText);
   }
});

xhr.open("GET", "http://testapi.myserver.de/api/Cart");
xhr.setRequestHeader("authorization", "Basic blabla");
xhr.setRequestHeader("cache-control", "no-cache");

xhr.send(data);
```

And this is the response:

```
HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently
Date: Thu, 02 Jun 2016 09:44:11 GMT
Server: Apache/2.2.16 (Debian)
Location: http://50743.your-way.eu/webinar/56?pn/api/Cart
Vary: Accept-Encoding
Content-Encoding: gzip
Content-Length: 274
Keep-Alive: timeout=15, max=100
Connection: Keep-Alive
Content-Type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1
```

The really weird thing is, we are using IIS not Apache.

Here are the request headers:

When made with XHR I only get the OPTIONS request here:

```
Host: testapi.mywebserver.de
Connection: keep-alive
Pragma: no-cache
Cache-Control: no-cache
Access-Control-Request-Method: GET
Origin: http://localhost
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/50.0.2661.102 Safari/537.36
Access-Control-Request-Headers: authorization, cache-control
Accept: */*
Referer: http://localhost/
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, sdch
Accept-Language: de-DE,de;q=0.8,en-US;q=0.6,en;q=0.4
```

The Browserheaders:

```
Accept: text/html, application/xhtml+xml, image/jxr, */*
Accept-Language: de-DE,de;q=0.8,en-GB;q=0.5,en;q=0.3
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/46.0.2486.0 Safari/537.36 Edge/13.10586
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
Host: testapi.mywebserver.de
Connection: Keep-Alive
```

Comment: DNS configuration?

Comment: Could you go a bit more detailed?

Comment: Not really, without more to go on.

Comment: Which DNS configuration do you mean exactly?

Comment: At some stage, your HTTP requests are being routed to _your-way.eu_ instead of your server. You'll need to examine each step in the request pipeline as there's no way I can see what's going on in your environment. I suggested your DNS configuration may be the issue as there may be a redirection set up for whatever reason.

Comment: do you have a virus/extension that hacks ur calls?

Comment: Don't think so, I tried the same call on a different computer and got the same result.

Comment: @ChrisPickford I added the calling code and the response headers.

Comment: Does it happen when you use some command line client like `curl` for me it too looks like some adware/adware proxy meddling with your requests

Comment: @csharpfolk it does only happen when I execute the exact JavaScript code. If I call the URL directly in the browser or in fiddler it works fine

Comment: You are getting a response from your server with a HTTP 301 redirection. The issue lies on your server, maybe an IIS/Apache configuration for your endpoint.

Comment: @ChrisPickford but why does it work in fiddler then?

Comment: No idea, look at your configuration!

Comment: @ChrisPickford ok, I could track it down to an issue in the IIS, but I cannot find in the web.config of the IIS any suspicious entries. Do you know any other place where this could be configured?

Comment: Global configuration? Malware?

Comment: I checked the following files:
C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\Config\web.config
C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\Config\machine.config
[webapp]\web.config

Comment: Could you post exactly headers that are sent do server when you do XHR request and when you do the same request using browser, maybe XHR sends some additional headers that are detected by the remote server